# Show more comments using ajax with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax

With Django I made a Show more comments button using ajax. This system works, but the problem is that there are form fields in the comments I brought in this way, and when I click the more button, csrf_token does not appear in this comment field. As such, I get a csrf_token error when I submit the form. I leave my codes below.

To solve this problem, I ran the form with the get method, but as such, the function in the views directs me to the page with JsonResponse. Another solution was to give the header information csrf_token, but that didn't solve the problem either.

blog_detail.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var limit = $(this).attr('limit')
    var page = document.getElementById('pagination')
    var blog_comment_list = $('#blog-comment-list')
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: "{% url 'load-more-comments' %}",
      data : serializedData,
      success: function(response){
        blog_comment_list.html(response.comment_html)
        if (page.value >= limit){
          $('#submit_button').hide()
        }
        page.value = parseInt(page.value)+1
      },
    })
  })
})

</script>

<div id="blog-comment-list">
  {% include 'front_end/blog/comment/partial-comment.html' %}
</div>
 <form method="GET" id="load_form" limit="{{num_pages}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{details.id}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2" id="pagination">
 <input type="submit" name="load" value="Load More" id="submit_button">
 </form>
```

partial-comment-html

```
<div class="media-holder mt-5">
  <h3 class="title mb-3">All Comments</h3>
  {% for item in comments %}
  <div class="infinite-container">
  <div class="media mb-5">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle box-shadow mr-4" alt="image" src="{{item.owner.get_image_or_default}}" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h6>{{item.owner.name}}  {{item.owner.surname}}</h6> 
      <br>
      <small><span style="font-size:14px;" class="stars-container stars-{% widthratio item.rate.rate 1 20 %}" id="stars">★★★★★</span></small>
      <div class="comment-date"> <span class="date">{{item.created_date|naturaltime}}</span>
      </div>
      <p>{{item.content}} </p>
      
      <div align="center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show-answers" id="comment-id-{{item.id}}">{% if item.comments.all %}Cevapları Görüntüle ({{item.comments.count}}){% else %}Cevap Ver{% endif %}</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="generic-comment" id="generic-comment-id-{{item.id}}" style="display:none;">
        <!-- -->
        <div class="infinite-generic-comment">
        <form action="{% url 'comment-answer' %}" method="POST" id="answer_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{item.id}}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Cevap Ver" name='generic_comment' class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <input type="submit" value="Cevap Ver" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            </div>
           </div>
          </form>
          {% for comment in item.comments.all %}
          <div class="media mb-2">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle box-shadow mr-4" alt="image" src="{{item.owner.get_image_or_default}}" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h6>{{comment.owner.name}}  {{comment.owner.surname}}</h6> 
              <div class="comment-date"> <span class="date">{{comment.created_date|naturaltime}}</span>
              </div>
              <p>{{comment.content}} </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<script>
 
var aTag = document.getElementsByClassName('show-answers')
for (let i = 0; i< aTag.length; i++){
  aTag[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    var generic = document.getElementById(`generic-${event.target.id}`)
    if (generic.style.display == 'none'){
      $(`#generic-${event.target.id}`).slideDown('slow')
    }
    else{
      $(`#generic-${event.target.id}`).slideUp('slow')
    }
  })
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#answer_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize()
    var url = $(this).attr('action')

    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        },
        //headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: url,
      data:serializedData,
      success: function(response){
        if (response.success){
          $('#answer_form').trigger('reset')
          Swal.fire(
          'Başarılı!',
          'Cevap onaya gönderildi',
          'success'
          )
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

views.py

```
def answer_comment(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        comment = Comment.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('comment_id'))
        comment.comments.create(owner=request.user, content=request.POST.get('generic_comment'))
        return JsonResponse({'success':True},status=200)
    return JsonResponse({'success':False}, status = 403)
```

Note: I tried the csrf_exempt decorator function, but still could not solve the problem.

The methods I use are available in the script tag in partial-comment-html. How can I solve this problem. As I said, when I press the load more button, the necessary form fields to respond to a comment are just below these comments and when load more with ajax, the csrf_token information is deleted in these form fields, and nothing happens in new comments.

Note 2: When {{csrf_token}} is entered, I added the hidden input field with javascript myself, but Django realized that I added it and prevented me.

Comment: what do you mean by "but Django realized that I added it and prevented me"? have you ever logged `serializedData` to see the data? is a csrf token empty there? I dont use jquery but with vanilla XHR request `i.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}")` works fine in a similar setup.

Comment: ```$.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        },
        //headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
    });```  Yes, I used this structure, I tried the part in the comment line and the part that is not, but the problem is that there is no ```{{csrf_token}}``` in my form element.